# Detecting touch event outside certain UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

In my app, to click a button will pop up a UIView, now I want to click anywhere outside of the UIView to dismiss the UIView.
I have tried adding a large transparent button under the UIView, invoke the button action to dismiss the UIView, but the button can't be expanded to Fullscreen because of the top navigationbar and bottom tabbar
Is any other way to achieve?

Comment: Let's give it a try like this, I've seen it done like this somewhere so hope it will help you too, though can't remember exactly now how it was. Anyway, you say when I click a button `UIView` comes up? Now where is the `UIButton` located? I guess it sits on top of `UIView`? say that `UIView` is called `myView`. Now, make `myView` subclass of `UIControl` -- now there is certain method you can override and dismiss the UIView there. Maybe that method is that you can add `targetAction` to `myView` on user tap, and do the dismissing there. Hope I helped somehow.

Comment: I don't really understand, when click outside of MyView, any action to trigger?

Comment: Say you have button A. When you click button A, View B appears right? But Button A probably is subview of some other view, say view C. What I suggested was make view C subclass of `UIControl`, then add a action method that will get invoked when user clicks the view C and dismiss view B in that method. I think it should work ..

Comment: I need to click anywhere outside of myView to dismiss it, not only click the view C

Comment: Ok, I thought you had kind of setup where clicking outside the view which you want to hide, was equivalent to clicking `view C`.

Comment: ok, just giving you a link where dismissing a number pad is discussed by clicking outside it, maybe it will be helpful to you in some way. http://forums.bignerdranch.com/viewtopic.php?f=223&t=4193

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A giant `UIButton` it's not very good solution to your problem. You can simple use a `UIGestureRecognizer` for that.

You can allocate one like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapImageRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(dismissPopUp)];
```

Then, just add the gesture to the views you want to respond to the selector chosen.

```
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapImageRecognizer];
```

and possibly others

```
[self.navBar addGestureRecognizer:tapImageRecognizer];
//etc
```

Just don't forget to implement the method used by the gesture recognizer

```
-(void)dismissPopUp
{
   //your dimiss code here
}
```

Comment: The code will dismiss the pop up view, but after that tap won't work on buttons, tableview cells and all the UIControls. Any suggestion?

Comment: Late but you have to remove the gesture recognizer with removeGestureRecognizer like this [self.view removeGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)]. Of course, you would have to keep a reference to the gesture recognizer.